# Get Random item from table without repetition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an application where I have to display a question from a list without repetition.

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetQue()
{
    var result = obj.tblQuestions
        .OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid())
        .Select(o => new { o.id, o.Question, o.Opt1, o.Opt2, o.Opt3, o.Opt4 })
        .Take(1);
    return result;
}
```

Currently I am getting a random question but with repetition. How do I get a record without repetition?

Comment: Why are you just taking a single one? The `OrderBy()` should take care of the random sequencing since you are using a Guid, so just return the entire collection and output each one as you need as opposed to calling this same method multiple times. Without knowing a bit more about how you are implementing this, it could be difficult to provide a better suggestion.

Comment: You can use random between the length of the list and 0, then erase the element from the list and so on until the list gets empty

Comment: Shuffle the table just once. Then just get the data one by one.

Comment: Guids are a tool to generate *unique* values; they're not a tool to generate *random* values.  **You should not be using guids to generate random numbers**.  Use a random number generator for that.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, you can get elements one by one, using a random, and then remove the selected elements from list. Repeat this until the list is empty.

I am not gving yu exactly the code necessary for your case, you will still need to adapt it to your classes, but this is the principle it shoud respect:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int randomId;
Random rand = new Random();
if (list.Count != 0)
{

        randomId = rand.Next(list.Count);
        var randomElement = list[randomId];
        list.RemoveAt(randomId);
        return randomElement;
}
```

This gets the random elements from a list of integers, considering your list is the data iside a class, not the one you should renew, of course.

Answer (score -1):

```
public ActionResult GetNextQuestion(int[] prevs = null)
{
    var que = GetQue(prevs);
    var ids = new int[] { que.id};

    if(prevs != null)
        ids = ids.Concat(prevs);

    ViewBag.list = ids;

    return View(que);
}



public dynamic GetQue(int[] prevs = null)
{
    using (var obj = new Db())
    {
        var result = obj.tblQuestions;

        if(prevs != null)
           result = result.Where(e => !prevs.Contains(e.id));

        result = result.OrderBy(r => new Guid())
                       .Select(o => new { o.id, o.Question, o.Opt1, o.Opt2, o.Opt3, o.Opt4 });

        return result.First();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will return the items in the same order 100% of the time; it'll just start in an arbitrary place in the sequence.

Answer (score -2):

Source:[how to avoid number repeation by using random class in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602953/how-to-avoid-number-repeation-by-using-random-class-in-c)

If you add the items to a list as you cycle them, you can check the list to see if its been added or not. I'm pretty rookie, so i cant really code it out for you, but the idea is there. Make a seperate list for the entries you've already cycled through, then do maybe an if statement to check if the next entry is in the list before executing it.

I would have done this in a comment, but i dont have 50 rep, so i cant start a comment chain. :/